# Check if image contains text

Tags: image, text, contains

I want to detect and extract texts in a natural image if it contains as google vision do. I found a library on GitHub that detect regions on image to find texts and after detection it does OCR. I want it to be faster and before text detection and extraction, I want to check if an image contains text or not.
I know I can run OCR on it but I want it to be faster than that. If it contains text then it should OCR, if not it should discard the image. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Aforge.NET or OpenCV?

Comment: using this and it contains Tensorflow and tessaract https://github.com/azmiozgen/text-detection

Comment: so what issue are you facing currently?

Comment: it is not  fast enough, so I need to categorize pictures with or without text in advance. if a picture   contains text  I should use this library. so i need to categirize image  with or without text

Comment: using which language are you planning to implement this on?

Comment: github.com/azmiozgen/text-detection is writen in phyton

Comment: give that a go https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/ . Its written in C# though